# Javascript: indicate when item in list clicked?

Tags: javascript

This javascript fails to show the line number of item clicked.

```
    function registerHandlers() {
      var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        as[i].onclick = function() {
          alert(i);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```

And HTML:

```
In my life, I used the following web search engines:<br/>
      <a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>
      <a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a><br/>
      <a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br/>
```

Comment: Also typically you will want to add scripts at the bottom of the page to avoid further bugs of unloaded content.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't called `registerHandlers()` anywhere on the document...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script>
    function registerHandlers() {
      var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        as[i].addEventListener('onclick', function() {
          alert(i);
          return true;
        });
      }
    }
    //Call Function Here on window load
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
               registerHandlers();
    });
    </script>

      In my life, I used the following web search engines:<br/>
      <a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>
      <a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a><br/>
      <a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br/>



    </body>
    </html>
```